# What plant do I be, whether an apple or a tree?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Curved like a circle.
>   Knotty sides.
>   My color is .  _..  . (old women brains).
>   Specks of evil on my enlightened self.
>   A strong mask to hide my true self.
>   To protect the weak of what I am.
>   What plant am I?

This is just something I sort of made off of the top of my head. Sorry in advance if it sucks and/or is easily solvable!

EDIT: I only just now realized that I screwed up that Morse Code. Heh heh, sorry!

UPDATE 3/30/19: So, this is going unanswered then I presume?

Comment: Only color I can think of that matches the .__.. pattern is rot13(crnpu, juvpu vf nyfb n sehvg), but that doesn't seem to fit any other part of the puzzle.

Comment: I thought the dot/dash sequence was morse code, but it translates to "etne". Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Thinking about it logically, even if we found out what the colour was, how would it narrow everything down to one plant? From this I deduce that the colour cannot be a natural colour like Green, Brown or Red. The colour must then be Blue or Yellow

Comment: Well the morse code is now EDE. If it was converted to RGB with E being max and D being min, it would be magenta. No clue what to make of it. Apparently there could be a pun with "Fuchsia" but I don't think it fits the bill

Comment: Well #ede is also magenta in hexadecimal however I see JellyBean said this and it is not the case. #ede000 is a code for yellow however I hope that this isn't the case. Could it also be an acronym? There are many acronyms for EDE

Comment: Well Ede translates to "help" in Haitian Creole. But I don't think it's the one you are referring to.

Comment: Decoding from base 64, "ede" becomes "y"

Comment: @Adam and yellow is the only common colour which starts with 'Y' !

Comment: @Natasha I think it is most likely Yellow even if this isn't the proper way to work it out given all of the context clues and the response to your answer

Comment: Nahh, not unanswered... I'm still working on it. A clue, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather stupid and super-vague puzzle that I made, so it's no wonder that no-one figured it out. Then again, this 
WAS my first question on this site, so I was pretty inexperienced with making proper puzzles back then.

Anyhoo, here's my official answer to my own question.

(The Stupid) Solution:

> Banana

The Explanation:

Curved like a circle

> Bananas have a curved shape, like, or similar to, a circle.

Knotty Sides

> Bananas have that one elongated and knotty end on them.

My color is . _.. . (old women brains)

> This is a conveluted part. ". _.. ." is Morse for "EDE." If we translate that to their numerical position in the alphabet, and we get "575." Now for the other part, we have some puns: old women=nanny+ brains=motor-nannymotor. This sounds like **nanometers**. Combinee with be 575, we get 575 nanometers, the wavelength for the color yellow. Like I said, this is pretty dumb. It's even more so without any given context (which was not given.) And bananas are yellow.

Specks of evil on my enlightened self.

> Most bananas, which are yellow(~white=good/enlightened), have a few black(=evil) specks on them.

A strong mask to hide my true self. To protect the weak of what I am.

> Bananas have peels to protect their fleshy insides.

A pretty stupid puzzle for sure. Now that mystery is cleared up!

Answer (score 4):

Im going to guess that it is

> A watermelon

Because

> It is curved *like* a circle but it is slightly elongated. A watermelon can have the appearance like a present, with stripes focused towards the top and bottom where they knot together. It is green which fits the length of ".--.." . An "enlightened" watermelon would show the soft red insides which contain very annoying (and evil) black seeds. A watermelon has a very hard shell that protects the fleshy inside.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the answer is

> an orange [fruit]
>   1. It's curved like a circle
>   2. knotted as in the top and the bottom seems like a knot [ where it's connected to the branch and the bottom ]
>   3. its color is orange hope that's the color of old women's brains
>   3. has a case to protect the inner weak fruit
>   4. has specs all over

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> Lime (or lemon)

Curved like a circle

> Yes it is.

Knotty sides

> Yes! At least I think so. The place where it connects to the branch, there seem to be knots.

My colour is

> Yellowish?! Not sure if it is like old women brains. I've never checked it out.

Specks of evil on my enlightened self

> Yes it is evil. Try eating it. And enlightened = light (which is usually yellow in graphics related to enlightenment)

A strong mask to give my true self.

> Has a strong outer shell and looks like a tiny little thing, but it's very sour in reality.

To protect the weak of what I am

> I think so.

**Update:**

This is what I've progressed so far (after @JamesDouglas 's comment on the question)

> The Morse code translates to `EDE`.

**Update 2:**

> What do old women do?
>
>  **Yell**(ow) *(No intended offence to anyone)*
>  
>  P.S. I haven't still figured out what brains refers to here.

Comment: I couldn't figure out a proper reason, but lime seemed to fit in all the other clues. And it's colour is yellow which is **a bit** close to the peachish colour of the brain.

Comment: @RewanDemontay does the code for colour has anything to do with HTML colour codes?

Comment: Umm.... brain can be engine? Or steering wheel? Or the self driving software? Or the driver?

Comment: And by type of measurement, do you mean the measurement scales like CGS or SI?

Comment: To run an engine, fuel is required which can be measured in gallon, litre etc.

Comment: Then the most common seems to be metre, which sounds like "meet her"?

Comment: Meter as the unit meter or the instrument meter?

Comment: For measuring radii etc. - Nanometers?

Comment: Oh okay. Then meter as a unit right?

Comment: I think I just got the pun; 'unit' sounds like 'you knit', which is something that old women do. I am still not sure how we get meter from brains though...

Comment: @JamesDouglas maybe you should confirm it from the OP?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you may be

> a **pumpkin**

Curved like a circle.

> Well, yes.

Knotty sides.

> Pumpkins are often irregular, with small knots or scars on their rind.  (Might also reference the stem, but that seems unlikely)

My color is . _ _. . (old women brains).

> Orange seems to be the theme here, and this holds for a pumpkin.

Specks of evil on my enlightened self.

> Pumpkin rinds often have little specks on them.  (Or, perhaps, the seeds, but that seems less likely)

A strong mask to hide my true self. To protect the weak of what I am.

> The outer rind, protecting the soft innards.

Answer (score 1):

What plant am I?

> Ginger

Curved like a circle.

> While ginger is not spherical, it's edges are all curved

Knotty sides.

> Ginger is very knotty https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Ingwer_2_fcm.jpg/220px-Ingwer_2_fcm.jpg

My color is . _ _. . (old women brains).

> Light brown (not really sure what this riddle means)

Specks of evil on my enlightened self. A strong mask to hide my true self. To protect the weak of what I am.

> Ginger has a strong smell?

Am I going in the right direction?